# Reflection on PackageManager fails

Tags: android

I'm trying to access `PackageManager` via reflection. I can enumerate the methods and find getApplicationInfo. I can also execute `getApplicationInfo` on the reference I get via `reflection. getMethods()` works but `getMethod()` with `getApplicationInfo` throws a `no such method exception`.

```
Method method;
Method method2;
method = Class.forName(Context.class.getName()).getDeclaredMethod(
                    "getPackageManager");
Object manager;
manager = method.invoke(ctx);

// this works
ApplicationInfo testInfo = ((PackageManager) manager)
    .getApplicationInfo("com.package.class", 0);

// throws nosuchmethodexception
((PackageManager) manager).getClass().getMethod("getApplicationInfo");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [getMethod()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E...%29) method definition

```
public Method getDeclaredMethod(String name,Class...<?> parameterTypes);
```

So you need to pass the `class` instance of parameter types.

Replace

```
((PackageManager) manager).getClass().getMethod("getApplicationInfo");
```

with

```
((PackageManager) manager).getClass().getMethod("getApplicationInfo",int.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the parameter types to getMethod so it know what version to get.  What it's doing now is looking for a no parameter version, which doesn't exist.

See Class documentation:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29